# getting a 500 server error when bring up a page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

So I am getting a 500 server error when attempting to bring up a rhtml page in rails.  When I start the WEBrick server, I get the welcome to rails homepage. The name of the app is hello.  I generated the controller from the command line and it looks like

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
def there
end
end
```

I have my view (there.rhtml) in views/hello/there.rhtml.  However the http://localhost:3000/hello/there gets a 500 sever error.  I am currently running this on a vista box.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the route ? It is defined in routes.rb . Also you can try checking the development logs to see what exactly is the issue .

Comment: thanks, the routes were fine, however after check the development logs turns out was a problem with sqlite3.  got it installed working fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

could post the error log message? as Nm suggested it can be a route problem and if it is try to add this route in routes.rb file

```
map.connect '/hello/there', :controller => 'hello', :action => 'there'
```